# SharePoint 2010 Foundation with Search Server Express 2010 VS SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, development, 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I am wondering if I install SharePoint Foundation 2010 with Search Server Express 2010, will I have a product as good as SharePoint Foundation 2013's search features?

I am looking to make my SharePoint Foundation 2010 as good as possible and I know the search feature in 2010 is not up to snuff.

Please help me get a better insight than I am able to find on the internet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SSE isn't going to be as good as SharePoint Foundation 2013 (which is full blown Enterprise + FAST search, just like SharePoint Standard/Enterprise 2013).  Foundation 2013 is just limited to a single instance of the Search Service Application.